# Handling JPG format by Pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, jpeg

```
from tkinter import *
from glob import glob
import demoCheck
import random
import quitter
from PIL import ImageTk

gifdir = 'd:/Python/Jupyter/Programming Python/Chap 8 - GUI/pic/'


class buttonpics(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, dir='./gifs/', **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        self.lbl = Label(self, text='None', bg='blue', fg='red')
        self.lbl.pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.btn = Button(self, text='Press me', bg='white', command=self.draw)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.quitter = quitter.Quitter(self)
        self.quitter.pack(anchor=S)
        self.files = glob(dir+'*.jpg')
        self.images = [(file, ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=file))
                       for file in self.files]

    def draw(self):
        name, photo = random.choice(self.images)
        self.btn.config(image=photo)
        self.lbl.config(text=name)


buttonpics(dir=gifdir).mainloop()
```

The codes are trying to load jpg formatted pictures to Tkinter through Pillow's ImageTk module. However, the system generated the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "d:/Python/Jupyter/Programming Python/Chap 8 -
> GUI/buttonpics-func.py", line 31, in <module>
>     buttonpics(dir=gifdir).mainloop()   File "d:/Python/Jupyter/Programming Python/Chap 8 -
> GUI/buttonpics-func.py", line 22, in __init__
>     self.images = [(file, ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=file))   File "d:/Python/Jupyter/Programming Python/Chap 8 -
> GUI/buttonpics-func.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
>     self.images = [(file, ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=file))   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 89,
> in __init__
>     image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 58,
> in _get_image_from_kw
>     return Image.open(source)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2930,
> in open
>     raise UnidentifiedImageError( PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'd:/Python/Jupyter/Programming Python/Chap 8 -
> GUI/pic\\IMG_4147.jpg' Exception ignored in: <function
> PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x00000226CF6CFD30> Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118,
> in __del__
>     name = self.__photo.name AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

If the extension is changed to png, the program can be run smoothly. Does this result from a compatibility issue with jpg format or there are some other reasons? Thank you for the help!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `pillow` should work with `.jpg` without problem. I never had problem with `jpg` but `pillow` may use external C/C++ libraries to work with different formats and if you don't have C/C++ library for `jpg` then it may have problem with this format.

Comment: Thank you for the notice. I have posted the complete error message.

Comment: I get the same `UnidentifiedImageError` when I try to open file which is not image. So you may have one of two problems: (1) your `IMG_4147.jpg` is not image or it is not JPG (try to open it in any imge viewer to see if it can open it and display its properties). (2) pilow needs [external libraries](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/installation.html#external-libraries) - to work with JPG it needs C/C++ library `libjpeg` and you may have to install it manually.